# i18n vue is not working when changing locale, using rules in text field of vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

Using Vuei18n and Vuetify make me confuse this point

This is my code (I noted the weird thing in-line):

```
<v-form @submit.prevent="login" v-model="valid" ref="form">
  <v-text-field
    prepend-icon="person"
    name="login"
    :label="$t('Login')" <-- This line is still translated automatically
    type="email"
    v-model="email"
    :rules="[v => !!v || $t('E-mail is required')]" <-- This line is not translated automatically
  ></v-text-field>
  ...
</v-form>
```

How can I translate automatically the message under the input form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a computed emailRules,

```
computed: {
    emailRules() {
      return [
        v => !!v || $t('E-mail is required')
      ];
    }
  },
```

Then modify your line :rules in your "v-text-field"

```
:rules="emailRules"
```

Comment: Not working, the only solution for me is reset validation (this.$refs.form.resetValidation());

Comment: Not working, dunno why got accepted. This fails.

Answer (score 4):

I think vuetify takes the message when rule has just to fail.

I did this mixin based on update rules when locale has changed, in order to refresh rules message.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  data: () => ({
    formActive: true,
  }),
  computed: {
    requiredRules() {
      return this.formActive
        ? [(val: string) => !!val || this.$t('errors.requiredField')]
        : []
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateLocale() {
      this.formActive = false
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.formActive = true
      })
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution of [SteDeshain](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8571#issuecomment-652441704) from this open github issue works for me:

template:

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="userState.username"
    :rules="[rules.required, rules.mail]"
>
    <template #message="{ message }">
        {{ $t(message) }}
    </template>
</v-text-field>
```

js:

```
data () {
  return {
    show1: false,
    rules: {
      required: v => !!v || 'rules.notEmpty',
      mail: v=> /^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$/.test(v) || 'rules.mail'
    }
  };
},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
         <v-select
              :items="getAllPriceGrups"
              item-text="name"
              @input="getPrices"
              v-model="priceG"
              filled
              :rules="rulesRequired($t('global.needToFillOut'))"
              return-object
          ></v-select>

 methods: {
    rulesRequired(role) {
      return [value => !!value || role];
    },
}
```

This works for me!